# Is there any good extension (module) for Kohana 3.2.2 framework, that working with Excel files?

Tags: php, kohana, phpexcel, kohana-3.2

I need to compose some xls(x) files, but don't know a good extension (module) for Kohana 3.2.2 framework, I know about PHPExcel ( a lot of links and repos I found ), but the most of them based on a PEAR library, that I'm not supporting in my project, maybe someone knows a good solution for that?

So I need a link with good documentation and module for that. Thanks.

**UPD**.

I made a first test for PHPExcel Library through this code:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
                ->setCellValue('B1', 'world!');

            // header("Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel");
            // header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='simple.xls'");

            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,'Excel2007');    
            $name = $objWriter->save('docs/MyExcel12.xlsx');

            $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/docs/MyExcel12.xlsx";
            /*      
            if (file_exists($file))
            {
                header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
                header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
                readfile($file);                
            }*/

            if (file_exists($file))
            {
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
                header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
                readfile($file);
            }
```

I see a file that was created after this code apply, but browser not forcing download it, as u can see I've used different headers, but do not have my file out. Help!?

**UPD** Also I have used:

```
            header("Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel");
            header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='simple.xls'");

            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,'Excel5');   
            $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

But have error (instead of file):

```
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

I made a redirect, but as I think it is not a solution anyway:

```
    $this->request->redirect('docs/new.xlsx');
```

Comment: PHPExcel has absolutely __NO__ dependencies on PEAR

Comment: Are you using this code in `Controller_Template` or `Controller`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating PHPExcel into Kohana http://www.flynsarmy.com/2010/07/phpexcel-module-for-kohana-3/

Comment: Thanks, but in what directory I must to upload the Spreadsheet class?

Comment: According to the notes, it goes in the classes/vendor/phpexcel directory

Comment: In the modules? Or Application/Classes?

Comment: Ok, I'm added it as is, but have error: `$objWriter->save('php://output');`, net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.

Comment: Then you're going to need to find somebody who knows Kohana... I know a bit about PHPExcel, but not about using it from within frameworks